# Find the sum of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Find the sum of $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}$$  I found that $$\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{1}{8(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{4(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{8(2k+3)}$$ but that expression doesn't give much. And I don't know if that sum can become telescoping somehow.
I know that the sum $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$ telescopes, but after we time every term by $\frac{1}{2k+3}$ that property doesn't work anymore

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{4(2k+1)}=\dfrac{2}{8(2k+1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:)**

$$\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{1}{8(2k-1)}-\frac{2}{8(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{8(2k+3)}=\dfrac18\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)-\dfrac18\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+3}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

This can be considered a special case of the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik formula 0.243.2
$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{[p+(k-1)q](p+kq)\cdots [p+(k+l)q]} = \frac{1}{(l+1)q}\frac{1}{p(p+q)\cdots (p+lq)}.$$ Alternatively work with the partial fraction and split one of the 3 terms into 2 such that we have an even number of terms, each term a quadratic in the summation variable:
$$\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{1}{8(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{4(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{8(2k+3)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{8(2k+1)}-\frac{1}{8(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{8(2k+3)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{(k-1/2)(k+1/2)}-\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{(k+1/2)(k+3/2)}\leadsto\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{24}.$$
Here each of the two terms is basically of the form
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}$$. The differences of the two digamma-functions are simple because it has the recurrence $$\psi(z+1)=\psi(z)+1/z$$.

Answer (score 2):

It still telescopes. The $k$-th term has the form
$$a_k-2a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}$$ where $a_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.
The sum of the first $n$ terms is
$$a_1-a_2-a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$$
so the overall sum will be $a_1-a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the partial sum,
\begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}
&=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+3}\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}\frac{1}{2k-1}\\
&=\frac{a_n}{8}-\frac{a_{n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-1}{4}+
\frac{a_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}-1-\frac{1}{3}}{8}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\right)a_n+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+O(1/n)=\frac{1}{12}+O(1/n)
\end{align*}
where $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}$. Hence,
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{1}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can always write out the first few terms of the series and see what happens:

$k=1: \frac18 - \frac{1}{12} + \frac1{40}\\
k=2: \frac1{24} - \frac1{20} + \frac1{56}\\
k=3: \frac1{40}-\frac1{28}+\frac1{72}\\
k=4: \frac1{56}-\frac1{36}+\frac1{88}\\
k=5: \frac1{72}-\frac1{44}+\frac1{104}$

Look at those diagonals, such as $\frac1{40}-\frac1{20}+\frac1{40}$, and see how they total to $0$? Everything should go away in this fashion, except for the three terms in the top-left corner: $\frac18-\frac1{12}+\frac1{24}=\frac1{12}$.

The trick now is just to formalize that observation, and the other answers here should help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to partial fraction decomposition. The [Fourier-Legendre expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-LegendreSeries.html) of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind $E(x)$ (here denoted according to Mathematica's standard of regarding $x$ as the elliptic modulus) is given by
$$ E(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4}{(1-2n)(2n+1)(2n+3)}\,P_n(2x-1) $$
hence by applying $\lim_{x\to 1^-}$ to both sides we get
$$ 1 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4}{(1-2n)(2n+1)(2n+3)} $$
leading to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{4}{3}-1\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{12}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting potential connections not explored in the answers so far.

**The first connection is to multiple integrals**

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^n y^m \;arctanh (x y) \;dx \; dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+n)(2k+m)}$$

with the alternating sum being

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^n y^m \arctan (x y) \;dx \; dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k=1}}{(2k-1)(2k+n)(2k+m)}$$

The pattern starts with the single integral and continues on with triple and higher integrals.

*[It's also worth noting that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^n y^m \log (1-x y) \;dx \; dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+n+1)(k+m+1)}$$
and
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^n y^m \log (1+x y) \;dx \; dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(k+n+1)(k+m+1)}$$
Here the pattern again starts with the single integral and continues on with triple and higher integrals.]*

**The second connection is to Euler sums.**

Most (perhaps all) the single integral results for the above can be stated using Euler Sums, thus for arctanh with $n\ge0$

$$\int_0^1 x^{2n} \;arctanh (x) \;dx =\frac{1}{2n+1} \left( log(2)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \right)$$

$$\int_0^1 x^{2n-1} \;arctanh (x) \;dx =\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} $$

There is a more complex pattern for $\arctan(x)$ with $arccot(x)$ results interleaved. The simplest pattern is for $\log(1-x)$

$$\int_0^1 x^{n} \;\log(1-x) \;dx =\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} $$

I am stating all this because there appears to be a connection to Euler sums for the double integral you give as well, with $m\ge2$, the conjecture is:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x y^{2m-1} \;arctanh (x y) \;dx \; dy=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+2m-1)}=\frac{1}{4(m-1)}\left[ 1-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2k-1}\right]$$

Possibly a whole load more identities between infinite sums and Euler sums to be found.